# file system check error during start my centos 6 machine in virtual machine

Tags: linux

i am unable to recover from maintenance mode, can anyone describe the solution? attached screenshots for reference.[image]

Comment: Check BIOS date, looks like your system time is off.

Comment: If Panki's suggestion isn't the reason for the "inconsistency" and it continues to complain, boot up a livecd and fsck the filesystem as it suggests.